# how to guarantee that functions will be invoke one after another when your code used else where?

Tags: c++, function

i have set of functions calls that must be run one after another 
this was my code so i didn't plan much ahead, any way i have few functions that must run one after the other if not the code will be broken . 
also i don't want to set function inside function so that when first function end it will invoke the second. 
is there any better way ?
im using c++ by the way .

```
void ButtomPanelObj::onEnter()
{
    Sprite::onEnter(); //  func 1 must be first 
    createSpinButton(); //  func 2 must be after 1 
    createPayLinesLable(); //  func 3 must be after 2 
    createBetLable(); //  func 4 must be after 3 
    createTotalBetLable(); //  func 5 must be after 4 
    setWidgetsPosition();  //  must be last func  



}
```

Comment: Why would these functions be called out of order?

Comment: why you can't create new function callIt() which invokes them in right order?

Comment: If you call a function, it will execute in the exact order it is written. Just call your `onEnter()` function and they will execute in that order... or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Why do you want the set out of the function, if it is to be called after it?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you don't want anybody working on this code to be able to re-order the functions. The simple answer is that you can't. What you can do to work around the issue is extract these methods to a different class, make them private and have the other class have exactly one public method, which calls these methods in the required order.

Comment: @  Bart van Nierop yes this is what i want

Comment: Apparently each function prepares some data and/or creates some objects for use by the next function. A main problem is then that these functions communicate via **shared global variables** relative to the functions, not matter if those variables are technically member variables of an object. I think that's what's really bothering you, that at any point in the call sequence those variables exist but are uninitialized or whatever. Instead a function that produces something, a `create...` function, can simply *return* whatever it is producing. And the next function can take that as argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate the functions. If they have to be called in order, and called all the time, they shouldn't be accessible seperately. It could be something like that:

```
class ButtomPanelObj{
private:
    void createSpinButton();
    void createPayLinesLable();
    void createBetLable();
    void createTotalBetLable();
    void setWidgetsPosition();
public:
    void createStuff() {
        Sprite::onEnter(); //  func 1 must be first 
        createSpinButton(); //  func 2 must be after 1 
        createPayLinesLable(); //  func 3 must be after 2 
        createBetLable(); //  func 4 must be after 3 
        createTotalBetLable(); //  func 5 must be after 4 
        setWidgetsPosition();  //  must be last func  
    }
```

}

Now you can only call `createStuff()` from outside, which guarantees the function order you require.

Comment: this is what i have now more or less , still developer can move function and all the other functions will not work

Comment: you can never prevent other developers from changing private parts of your function. The only thing you can do is to provide a failproof public interface, combined with good documentation of the private sections, to prevent missusage. If you think on developer level, it is always possible to remove any fail-prevention within functions, if the developer wants to. So you can never completely secure it without restricting access to source code.

Comment: @user63898 if the developer has the source code, they can do *anything*. You can't stop them being stupid.